# How do I calculate $I = \int\limits_{t_a}^{t_b}{\left(\frac{d{x}}{d{t}}\right)^2 \mathbb dt}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I = \int\limits_{t_a}^{t_b}{\left(\frac{d{x}}{d{t}}\right)^2 \mathbb dt}$$

$x_a = x(t_a)$ and $x_b = x(t_b)$

I haven't integrated anything like this since a long time. Lost my powers of integration.

How do I calculate $I$?

Comment: Take some examples of functions $x(t)$ and see what you get.  Say, $x(t) = t^3$ or $x(t) = \sin(t)$.

Comment: Any additional information available?

Comment: $x$ is a straight line in 3D.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what function $x$ is of $t$, you can't do much.  You could integrate by parts, letting $u = dx/dt$ and $dv = (dx/dt)\,dt$, and then you get $du = (d^2 x /dt^2) \,dt$ and $v = x$.  But that doens't necessarily shed any more light than does the expression you've got already.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts could simplify things, (not only) when $\ddot{x}$ is a constant:
$$
I = \int \dot{x}^2 \, dt = \int \dot{x} \, dx = \dot{x}x - \int x\ddot{x} \, dt
$$

Comment: I don't believe this is equivalent since we have $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$, which means we really have two of them, thus one integral is not enough to sum all of the $dx$'s with respect to $dt$'s...