# Feynman problem on action

Tags: integration, physics, calculus-of-variations

It is very weird for me that a newbie can ask a new (may be silly, sorry...) question but must have 50 reputation to comment. When I see a good question  like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50425/293083) but have no answer   what I have to do? So I know that the integral
$$S = \frac{m}{2}\int\limits_{t_a}^{t_b}{\left(\frac{d{x}}{d{t}}\right)^2 \mathbb dt}$$
occurs in the famous [Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html). This is so called *action* for the free moving particle, i.e the particle that have only kinetic energy (KE). So the question keep in force: how to calculate the *action* $S$. Btw, such a question is on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100452/34652).SE too.

Comment: For a definite path $\;t\mapsto x(t)\;$ you must integrate the square of its derivative $\,(x(t)')^2\,$ but the point is not to calculate this integral but to find a path (i.e. a function $x$) such that the action $S$ is minimal (more generally an extrema).  
You don't really need to suppose that the function $x$ is derivable and could consider a regular sampling like in this [picture](http://wiki.physics.fsu.edu/wiki/images/7/73/Pathintegral.gif) (the derivative would be constant in every short integral and the sum of the squares rather large => this would not return the "least action"!).

Comment: The path for the free moving particle must be a straight line

Comment: Yes : between all the possible paths $\;t\mapsto x(t)\;$ we have to choose the one such that $S$ is minimal and indeed if you consider the straight line in the picture from $\;(x_0,t_0)\to (x',t')\;$ instead of the "broken" segments you will get the minimal $S$ (because every larger derivative would contribute too much).

Comment: (in the actual solution we are simply integrating the square of the constant $\;v:=\dfrac{x'-x_0}{t'-t_0}\;$ so that the action will be $\;S_{real}=\dfrac m2 \left(\dfrac{x'-x_0}{t'-t_0}\right)^2(t'-t_0)=\dfrac m2\dfrac{(x'-x_0)^2}{t'-t_0}$)

Comment: I'll let you meditate about all this since it is late here... I hope this clarified a little Feynman's great article,

Comment: (should all this discussion be unclear don't hesitate to ask for further details here or by editing your question)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you very much. Your answer is absolutely clear.Thanks again. So what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(comments converted in an answer)

For a definite path $\;t\mapsto x(t)\;$ you must integrate the square of its derivative $\,(\dot{x}(t))^2\,$ but the point is not to calculate this integral but to find the path (i.e. a function $x$) such that the action $S$ is minimal (more generally an extrema).

You don't really need to suppose that the function $x$ is derivable everywhere and could consider a regular sampling like in this picture :

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [fsu.edu](http://wiki.physics.fsu.edu/wiki/images/7/73/Pathintegral.gif))</sub>

(the derivative would be constant in every short integral and the sum of the squares rather large => this graph would clearly *not* return the "least action"!).

Between all the possible paths $\;t\mapsto x(t)\;$ we have to choose the one such that $S$ is minimal.
For the very simple Lagrangian $\;L=\frac 12\,m\,\dot{x}^2\,$ the function defined by the straight line from $\,(x_0,t_0)\to (x',t')\,$ in the picture will return the minimal $S$ (shortly because every larger derivative would contribute "too much").

In the actual solution we are thus simply integrating the square of the constant speed $\;v:=\dfrac{x'-x_0}{t'-t_0}\;$ so that the action will be :
$$S_{real}=\dfrac m2 \left(\dfrac{x'-x_0}{t'-t_0}\right)^2(t'-t_0)=\dfrac m2\dfrac{(x'-x_0)^2}{t'-t_0}$$

What to do next? Well read the excellent Feynman lectures to the end to discover (while studying non-relativistic quantum mechanics) that the path $x$ such that the action is minimal is not the only one of interest : **all paths play a role and contribute!**

But before that you may learn calculus of variation while studying classical mechanics (Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics) for example in one of these excellent references :

1. [Lev D. Landau and E. Lifshitz Mechanics](https://archive.org/details/Mechanics_541) : handwaving, deep insight and practical computations
2. [Goldstein Classical Mechanics](https://homepages.dias.ie/ydri/Goldstein.pdf) : with references to other works
3. [Vladimir Arnold Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/mech1/READING/Arnold_Clas_Mech_ch_1_2.pdf) (first pages only) : beautiful mathematical presentation by a master of geometry (more advanced at the end)

For more about the quantum mechanics method (all paths considered) and once you know some basis about QM say from the [first chapter of his Vol. 3](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html) you may read [Feynman's Nobel conference](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1965/feynman-lecture.html) and other references to [Feynman path integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation)  (extending an idea of Paul Dirac) :

4. [Feynman & Hibbs "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486477223)
5. [Taylor & all "Teaching Feynman's sum-over-paths quantum theory"](http://qu-bit.narod.ru/texts/feynman.pdf)