# How does one integrate $e^{iS(q)}$with respect to $q(t)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $q(t)$ be some function. Consider the integral

$$\int e^{iS(q)} Dq(t)$$

For example, suppose $S(q) = q^2$

Or suppose $$S(q) = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} m\dot{q}^2$$

Or suppose $$S(q) = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} m\dot{q}^2-V(q)$$

**My Question:**

How does one do a "functional" integral? How is this different from doing a regular integral?

I managed to do a functional derivative, but I am just struggling with this concept.

Comment: What books have you read? I recommend the book by Cartier and De-Witt.

Comment: Some links at the end of this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547949/21783) may help (Feynman's Nobel conference and following). The short answer is that the integration is not over $t$ but over the different possible functions ('paths') $t\mapsto q(t)$ with fixed start and end.